# Selecting the first consonant in a word (following a number of vowels)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to make a pig-latin translator and a problem arose when I tried to deal with words beginning in vowels. The aim would be that, for words with vowels at the beginning, the suffix would be the **first consonant** in the word + "ay" (Rather than the *first letter* in the word + "ay") For example 'ear' would be 'ear-ray' rather than 'ar-eay'

However, I am struggling to find a way to do this.

This i what I have so far:      (it is taken from a larger section of code)

```
elif word[0]=="a" or word[0]=="e" or word[0]=="i" or word[0]=="o" or word[0]=="u":
    for letter in word[1:]:
      while consonantfound == False:
        if letter!="a" and letter!="e" and letter!="i" and letter!="o" and letter!="u":
          consonantfound = True
          consonant = letter
    suffix = consonant + "ay"
    newWord = i + "-" + suffix
```

This made the program just fail to produce an output and continue to run.

I feel like the problem is to do with the sequence of loops but I have experimented with it and no solution presented itself. It could also be something else that I am not aware of.

Do you have a suggestions as to how to make it work?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
VOWELS = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

def first_consonant(word):
    for letter in word:
        if letter.lower() not in VOWELS:
            return letter

def pig_latin(word):
    return '%s-%say' % (word, first_consonant(word) or word[0])
```

It tries to find the first consonant in a word and appends ay to the end. If it's not present then it defers to the first letter of the word (I don't know if this is correct, but you can adapt it to your needs).

Answer (score 0):

We can get the next constonant and its index using a generator expression.  If there is no constotnant, we will return `(None, None)` instead

```
next(((letter, index) for index, letter in enumerate(word) if letter not in 'aioue'), (None, None))
```

We can break this down a little bit to understand what's going on.

`enumerate` is a function that returns an iterator that pairs elements in an iterable with their index.  So `list(enumerate('abc'))` is `[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]`. We want to get the index of the first consonant so we know where to slice.

`((letter, index) for index, letter in enumerate(word) if letter not in 'aioue')` is a generator expression.  A generator is will yield values one by one.  All this one does is filter out the vowels from our enumerated letters.

`next(generator, (None, None))` gets us the next item out of the generator (which will be the first item).  If there is no next item (a word of all vowels), it will return the second argument `(None, None)`

Comment: Sorry I am new to python and I am not really sure how to implement this into my code. Could you explain further?