# Python Pig Latin Converter (Words that start with consonants)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a string to pig latin. Most examples online don't take into consideration that if a word starts with multiple consonants, you must move all the consonant to the end (school --> oolschay). My version is currently working with the first letter being a vowel as well as grabbing those words that don't start with a vowel, however, I don't know how to stop it from grabbing each instance of the vowel in the word and not just the first instance.

Here is the code:

```
pigLatin = input("Convert message to pig latin: ")
wordList = pigLatin.lower().split(" ")
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
pigLatin = []
eachWord = []
for word in wordList:
    if word[0] in 'aeiou': #case where vowel is first
        pigLatin.append(word + 'yay')
    if word[0] not in 'aeiou':
        for letter in word:
            if letter in 'aeiou':
                pigLatin.append(word[word.index(letter):] + word[:word.index(letter)] +'ay')


print(" ".join(pigLatin))
```

Comment: What's pig Latin?

Comment: [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51479954/selecting-the-first-consonant-in-a-word-following-a-number-of-vowels/51480062#51480062) I made for a very similar question. To get the first *vowel*, you would just change `not in` to `in`.

Comment: Also, I think your approach using `word.index` will fail for words that start with more than one of some consonant, like `llama`

Comment: His `word.index()` call actually won't fail because he uses it to split the string at the **first vowel**, so it looks for the **first vowel** and it appends everything to the left of the vowel to the end of `pigLatin`.  Since `string.index()` gets the first index of the substring and we only want the first vowel, his code is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `break` statement in the inner for loop that iterates through each individual word.  It will jump out of the loop once you find a vowel.  Or at least I think that's the problem you're having (your question was a little confusing.)

Try this:

```
pigLatin = input("Convert message to pig latin: ")
wordList = pigLatin.lower().split(" ")
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
pigLatin = []
eachWord = []
for word in wordList:
    if word[0] in 'aeiou': #case where vowel is first
        pigLatin.append(word + 'yay')
    else:
        for letter in word:
            if letter in 'aeiou':
                pigLatin.append(word[word.index(letter):] + word[:word.index(letter)] +'ay')
                break


print(" ".join(pigLatin))
```

I also made your code style a little better by putting an `else` instead of `if word[0] not in 'aeiou':`

**Happy Coding!**